# Positional argument follows keyword - menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu.filemenu) - calculator

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having trouble making a calculator for college work, and I'm new to Python.

```
from tkinter import*
import math
import parser
import tkinter.messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("Joshua's Scientific Calculator")
root.configure(background ="powder blue")
root.resizable(width =False, height =False)
root.geometry("480x568+0+0")

calc = Frame(root)
calc.grid()

menubar = Menu(calc)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff =0)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu.filemenu) 
filemenu.add_command(label = "Standard")
filemenu.add_command(label = "Scientific")
filemenu.add_seperator()
filemenu.add_command(label = "Quit")

editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff =0)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "Edit", menu.editmenu)
editmenu.add_command(label = "Cut")
editmenu.add_command(label = "Copy")
editmenu.add_seperator()
editmenu.add_command(label = "Paste")

helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff =0)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "Help", menu.helpmenu)
helpmenu.add_command(label = "View Help")


root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

This is what I've done so far,  but no matter what I do, it keeps coming up with the error  positional argument follows keyword at menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu.filemenu)

Help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're more likely to get a response if you detail the steps you took to try to solve your error. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using the following construct

```
menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu.filemenu)
```

here, since you use `label=` it makes that argument a "keyword argument", and `menu.filemenu` is a "positional argument" because you didn't specify which parameter takes that argument.

Python's syntax doesn't allow that order, positional arguments MUST precede all keyword arguments.

You may use all arguments as positional or as keyword, depending on the signature of the function you call

Checkout python's [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html) for more details about [arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-argument) and [parameters](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-parameter).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, this error happens because you are using a positional argument after a keyword argument and it is not acceptable in python. I thing your code must be edited like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import math
import parser
import tkinter.messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("Joshua's Scientific Calculator")
root.configure(background="powder blue")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry("480x568+0+0")

calc = Frame(root)
calc.grid()

menubar = Menu(calc)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Standard")
filemenu.add_command(label="Scientific")
# filemenu.add_seperator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Quit")

editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
editmenu.add_command(label="Cut")
editmenu.add_command(label="Copy")
# editmenu.add_seperator()
editmenu.add_command(label="Paste")

helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
helpmenu.add_command(label="View Help")

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

This is what I got:

[image]